# How to start a grails webtest without starting the grails application?

Tags: grails, functional-testing, webtest

I am working with the webtest plugin as functional test component for grails.
It works fine, but is very slow - the whole application has poor response times (>1min per page) when under test. My feeling is that this is because the app, canoo webtest and the IDE (netbeans) are running in one JVM when I start my test through the IDE (`test-app functional:`)

So my goal is now to deploy the app to a stand-alone tomcat and run my tests against this tomcat instance.

I googled and found an old option `-nostart` for webtest which seem to be outdated.

So I googled some more and found the `-baseUrl=http://...` option in the current documentation. The docs say that with this option, the app will not be started and all tests will run against this baseUrl. But when I give it a try, grails still tries to start up jetty (at least, I get an error message saying that the port 8080 is already in use).

Any ideas? I am already thinking about using webtest stand-alone, but I like the groovy syntax of the plugin...

I'm using grails 1.3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try interactive mode as mentioned here: [Can I run grails integration & functional tests against a running server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877349/can-i-run-grails-integration-functional-tests-against-a-running-server)

If the -baseUrl option isn't working then I'd raise a JIRA issue.

cheers

Lee

Comment: ah! one comment in your link states that -baseUrl is working from 1.3.5 on. I use 1.3.4 - maybe I should upgrade :-)